# Как поделить Python2 консоль на части?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Как поделить условно на 4 части консоль в python2, например в одной части ввод переменной, в другой вывод этой переменной [image: Например как на картинке]

Comment: https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Для рисования таких окон есть https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html и для питона.

Comment: Ответ-ссылка — не ответ.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, [есть мнение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9493/1365), что в вопросах по поиску библиотек названия библиотеки достаточно.

Comment: @insolor в целом да. Но желательно, всё же, подробностей хоть каких-то добавить (:

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica я хотел написать ещё замечаний по поводу Windows, может завтра дополню чем-то интересным.

Comment: @insolor поиск библиотек сейчас онтопик?

Comment: @eri Вроде да...